# How to solve spark-submit error:Error: Failed to load class?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, build

I wrote a scala file as:

```
package cn.tedu.wordcount

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Driver {
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("wordcount")
    
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
    
    val data=sc.textFile("/Users/laiyinan/OneDrive/文档/书籍/大数据/达内BIG/大数据/大数据第四阶段/06-Spark/spark第一天/课后作业/data/word.txt", 2)

    val result=data.flatMap { _.split(" ")}
                   .map {(_,1)}.reduceByKey{_+_}
    
    result.foreach{println}               
  }
}
```

And I submit it into spark using the command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "cn.tedu.wordcount.Driver" /Users/laiyinan/Desktop/1902SparkDay01_jar.jar
```

I got this error every time:

[image]

> Error:Failed to load class cn.tedu.wordcount.Driver

I use Intellij Idea to build artefacts. Package path and class name are correct.

I’ve already tries some solutions, but none of them can fix it.

Comment: Could you show your driver class?

Comment: can you also share your build.sbt file or pom.xm ?

Comment: @ArtemAstashov sure no problem.

Comment: @koiralo I'm not using sbt or maven. I imported libraries in project structure.

Comment: @chucklai did you try to run in this way: ./bin/spark-submit --class "cn.tedu.wordcount.Driver" /Users/laiyinan/Desktop/1902SparkDay01_jar.jar ?

Comment: @ArtemAstashov I just tried. It doesn't work neither.

Comment: @chucklai ok, how do you build your jar?

Comment: @ArtemAstashov import scala sdk->add actifects, using type Jar->build actifects->A jar file in class folder

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using `sbt` to build and also use `sbt-assembly` plugin to make your application jar.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly